# Remove image from the last Finished page of Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How to customize last page (`wpFinished`) to only have a message, but keep the bottom buttons, like this:

[image]

I don't want the image on the left that is there by default.

I was trying to create new page, but don't know how to hide the default finished page or add bottom buttons (*Back*, *Finished*, *Cancel*) on new page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hide the `WizardBitmapImage2` control and extend remaining controls accordingly.

Something like this:

```pascal
[Code]

procedure ExtendFinishedPageControl(Control: TControl);
begin
  Control.Left := Control.Left - WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2.Width;
  Control.Width := Control.Width + WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2.Width;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2.Visible := False;

  ExtendFinishedPageControl(WizardForm.RunList);
  ExtendFinishedPageControl(WizardForm.NoRadio);
  ExtendFinishedPageControl(WizardForm.YesRadio);
  ExtendFinishedPageControl(WizardForm.FinishedLabel);
  ExtendFinishedPageControl(WizardForm.FinishedHeadingLabel);
end;
```

[image]